# Как сделать обновление рандома в Python?

Tags: python, discord.py, discord, случайные-числа, обновление

Я делал бота для дискорд, и мне понадобилось что бы он из списка выводил слова рандомные, только во второй и другие разы он эти слова повторяет, а мне нужно что бы он каждый раз, новое выводил из списка.
Код:

```
import discord
import random
from discord.ext import commands


TOKEN = 'май токен'
PREFIX = '!'
intents = discord.Intents().all()

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=PREFIX, intents=intents)



avtoriz = ['человек', 'авторизоваться', 'а']

for x in range(5):
      random_avtoriz = random.choice(avtoriz)



@bot.event
async def on_ready():
      pass

@bot.command()
async def а(ctx):
      await ctx.send("ъ")

@bot.command()
async def авторизация(ctx):
      await ctx.send(random_avtoriz)

@bot.command()
async def повтори(ctx, *, arg):
      await ctx.send(arg)


bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2):

При запуске программы создаётся (пять раз) переменная `random_avtoriz` и, в последствии, никак не обновляется.

Почему бы не вызывать `random.choice(...)` внутри хендлера, без этой переменной? Тогда мы каждый раз будем получать случайный элемент из массива.

```py
...

@bot.command()
async def авторизация(ctx):
      await ctx.send(random.choice(avtoriz))

...
```

Comment: Аа, спасибо, я попробовал, всё получилось)

Comment: @Человек, «спасибо» здесь выражается принятием ответа. См. [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)